# Firebase Realtime Database: Getting List of all users except the current user

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am building an app in React Native and Firebase. I have a user table in Firebase Realtime Database. This is what the table looks like[image: users table]
I want to get a list of all the users except the current user.
This is the code I am trying:

```
 const getUserList = async () => {
        const currentuid = currentuser.uid;
    try {
        const allusers = query(ref(database, 'users/'),endBefore(currentuid));
        console.log("searchusers: ", allusers);
        onValue(allusers, (snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            console.log("data: ", data);
            const users = Object.values(data);
            setUsers(users);
            });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving user data:', error);
        return [];
      }
}
```

This returns all the users, I want users whose uid is not equal to currentuid.
Using not() in the query doesn't work in the latest version but I am wondering if there is any alternative.

I guess I can get all users from DB and then use the filter function of javascript to achieve this as well but I wanted to achieve this result by directly querying the database

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, you have to use the [not-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in) operator. You'll be able to combine up to 10 `!=` (not equal) clauses on the `id` field with a logical `AND`. So a `not-in` query will return all documents where the `id` field exists, is not null, and does **not** match any of the comparison values. So if you need only one UID, add it to a list and pass the list to the query.

Comment: hey its didnt work in firebase realtime db, it was in firestore's documentation though

Comment: My answer was **never** related to the Realtime Database, but to Firestore. And to hear that it worked.

Comment: ohh! I was using firebase realtime database. and yes it didn't help my project but I learnt something new still so thank you

Comment: So you said that you used the solution above in Firestore, and it worked, right?